# Python pyODBC : Issue inserting into a sql server table with an identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

An INSERT statement that was created with Python gives me an error when I execute and commit it. I have taken a copy of the statement from Python and run it myself in SQL SERVER and it works fine there. The table I am trying to insert into has an identity column. When Python trys to execute it will give me an error saying what is below when I exclude the identity column in the statement

Table looks like this MY_TABLE ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, A INT, B INT)

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (A, B) VALUES(VALUE_A, VALUE_B);
```

"('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'MY_IDENTITY_COLUMN', table 'MY_TABLE'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")"

But when I try to include the value for the Identity column (I don't want to do this) I get the following error which makes sense as it's an identity column that we let the table auto-increment

"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'MY_TABLE' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

When I run the query in SQL SERVER the table fills the value for the Identity Column itself and auto-increments but for some reason when I run the statement in Python it does not do this and tries to pass a NULL

SQL SERVER version: 10.50.6560.0

Comment: You are trying to insert a value to an `IDENTITY` column, which you shouldn't unless you set `IDENTITY_INSERT OFF`.

Comment: correct, but like i stated above when i pass no value for that column I receive the first error 

also when i state no value i mean like this 
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (
IDENTITY_COLUMN,
A,
B, )
VALUES (VALUE_A, VALUE_B)

Comment: Exclude the column, thus way every thing will works just fine.

Comment: The first error is when I exclude the column

Comment: @Ilyes this should be the accepted solution. Otherwise you'd need to to add the identity off statement at the top of the sql then and turn it back ON at the end of the statement blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Recognising it's a little late but... I had the same problem recently using some old program and ODBC.  The solution was to create a View in SQL Server with only the columns required (i.e. A and B in your case) and then insert into that View.

Answer (score -1):

A little hard to tell without your code, but here is an example.

In database create a test table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test(  
ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   
Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL  
);
```

Then in Python specify the columns you are inserting into

```
import pyodbc

warecn = pyodbc.connect("Your Connection Stuff")

Inscursor = warecn.cursor()

Inscursor.execute("Insert into dbo.test(name) values ('This'), ('is'), ('a'), ('test')")


Inscursor.commit()
Inscursor.close()
del Inscursor
warecn.close()
```

Comment: That is what I am doing but Python seems to be trying to pass a NULL for the ID column even though like in your insert statement I do not try to insert into that column

Comment: Are you using INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (A, B) VALUES(VALUE_A, VALUE_B);? Without the IDENTITY_COLUMN listed?

Comment: Hhhmm. Could edit your question to include the code that is passing the values to VALUE_A and VALUE_B?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the loop or function in your python code that is passing the values for VALUE_A and VALUE_B. If you comment out the insert statement and use print('value A is {} and value B is {}'.format(VALUE_A,VALUE_B)) What gets printed?

Comment: oh sorry didn't understand the question, so i did that and ran the result in SQL SERVER and it works with no issues but when python executes it gives the first error